# Is correct wrapping <header> and <nav> tags

Tags: html

Is correct (semantically) wrapping `<header>` and `<nav>` tags to share in the background

example

```
<div id="background">
  <header> <!-- ... --> </header>
  <nav> <!-- ... --> </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: are you asking if your code is acceptable syntax? if so, then yes, its valid html structure

Comment: i want know if is a correct html5 structured

Comment: If html is valid then it is also correctly structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely correct.

You could have the header and nav nested, or not nested. Both are fine. For example you could use any of these:

```
<div class="wrapper">    
  <header>
    <nav></nav>
  </header>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">    
  <header></header>
  <nav></nav>
</div>

<section>    
  <header></header>
  <nav></nav>
</section>

<article>  
  <header></header>
  <nav></nav>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a useful thing to read: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_structural_elements

in short: yes, its valid html5 structure

"the `<div>` still has a perfectly valid use. You should use it when there is no other more suitable element available for grouping an area of content, which will often be when you are purely using an element to group content together for styling/visual purposes. A common example is using a  to wrap all of the content on the page, and then using CSS to centre all the content in the browser window, or apply a specific background image to the whole content."